# MvxExpandableListView GroupClick binding replaces group expanding functionality

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, expandablelistview

I am trying to do some additional stuff when a user taps on a group of an **`MvxExpandableListView`**, but apparently using the code below makes the group unable to expand a group anymore (if I delete the code below, the list works just fine; if I keep it, clicking the group won't expand it)

```
public IMvxCommand SelectGroupCommand => new MvxCommand<DrinkViewModel>(SelectGroup);
public void SelectGroup(DrinkViewModel drink)
{

}
```

This is the layout:

```
<Mvx.MvxExpandableListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/DrinksExpandableListView"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:groupIndicator="@null"
android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent"
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Drinks; ItemClick SelectDrinkCommand; GroupClick SelectCategoryCommand"
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/drinks_listitem"
local:MvxGroupItemTemplate="@layout/drinks_listheader"/>
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Could you post the complete layout ?

Comment: Done, I've added it in the description

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Yes, just update MvvmCross @GvSharma